# How to automate the ajax testing?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

I have a city field in a form that suggest city names on input, I want to test this scenario using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be specific to what you want to do with it like if you want to validate whether the right suggestions are retrieved or you just want to check if its working.

You may have some good reference from here:
[Link1](http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2011/10/14/sane-selenium-testing.html)
[Link2](http://www.infoq.com/articles/testing-ajax-selenium/)
[Link3](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp)

Comment: thanks for your kind reply sir, exactly you got the point i want to do both validation and verification.I think provided links will help me.